# What is the correct TypeScript type for a Quasar q-file element?

Tags: typescript, quasar-framework

I have a `q-file` with a template ref, it looks like this:

```
<q-file
  ref="myFile"
  v-model="image"
  @update:model-value="imageUpdate"
/>
```

Here is the ref (with my best guess at giving it a type):

```
const myFile: Ref<HTMLInputElement | undefined> = ref(undefined);
```

But when I use this I get a TypeScript error:

```
myFile.value.pickFiles();
```

This is the error:

```
Property 'pickFiles' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2339)
```

So I assume `HTMLInputElement` is the wrong type.

What is the correct type for `q-file`?

If there is no type, how do I create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Quasar component has its own instance type, you can import them from `'quasar'`. Here is an example with `QFile`:

```
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import { QFile } from 'quasar';

const fileRef: Ref<QFile | undefined> = ref();

function pickFiles () {
  if (myFile.value) {
    myFile.value.pickFiles();
  }
}
```

Pro tip: You can combine it with a type assertion to make the interaction to make everything simpler. It especially comes in handy when you want to do destructuring. This simplicity comes with a small cost, which is understanding the context that which the ref's value is defined, otherwise, you might get runtime errors.

```
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import { QFile } from 'quasar';

const fileRef = ref() as Ref<QFile>;

function pickFiles () {
  fileRef.value.pickFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I tried to extending the HTMLInputElement type as per below.

```
interface QFile extends HTMLInputElement {
    pickFiles: () => void;
}

const myFile: Ref<QFile | undefined> = ref(undefined);

if (myFile.value) {
    myFile.value.pickFiles();
}
```

The error has gone away, but I'm not sure if this is 100% correct.

The shape of the pickFiles method in the [q-file Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/file-picker#introduction) has this `pickFiles ([evt]) => void 0`.

Which I think indicates it takes an event? Or maybe an event array?

Either way, I couldn't get that working so I just removed the argument from the type. Please chime in if you know the correct way of doing it.